# Htaccess Hotlinking Prevention: Exclude a specific image from rule

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I have a working hotlinking prevention in the `.htaccess`. Everything works fine. However, I use an image of my website in email signature. After the hotlinking prevention, this image is now displayed in old mails also with the placeholder image (the image that describes that hotlinking is not allowed). Since I can't change the code for old mails from customers etc. of course, I want to exclude the old signature image from the hotlinking prevention. What line of code do I need to add to do this? I have tried various things and somehow it does not work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mywebsite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?bing.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yahoo.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|webp)$ https://www.dropbox.com/s/XXXXXXXXX/stop-hotlinking.png?raw=1 [NC,R,L]
```

Which line do I have to insert if my old signature image behind the following address and should be excluded from hotlinking prevention? Just this one file only.

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/old_signature.gif
```

Comment: Does really nobody know a solution?

Comment: Am I perhaps in the wrong forum section?

Comment: In my opinion, your question is basically a textbook example of what's on-topic for this Stack Exchange site. Unfortunately, we just don't get a lot of traffic here, so good questions remain unanswered sometimes. In my discretion, I've added a [bounty](/help/bounty) to this post to help try to attract an answer. This will feature it under the "Bountied" tab of the home page for the next seven days. Hopefully you'll get an answer soon!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Oh thank you very much for your nice words and the "bounty" (never heard about that before). I am curious if anyone can help. Have a nice day!

Comment: "I have tried various things and somehow it does not work." - It would be helpful to know what you have tried and what other directives you have in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: "Does really nobody know a solution?" - The question was lacking some general/relevant tags (it was only tagged "hotlinking") which I think is why I didn't see it initially.

Answer (score 4):

To allow that specific file, excluding it from the hotlink-protection script you just need to add the following *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) to the existing list of conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/wp-content/uploads/old_signature.gif
```

This checks that the requested URL-path (ie. the value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable) is *not* (denoted by the `!` prefix) the URL of the image you want to allow.

The `!` prefix negates the expression, so it is successful when it does not match (as with all the other *conditions* on this rule).

The `=` prefix operator makes this a lexicographical string comparison, as opposed to a regex (the default). So, this is essentially an "exact match" and no need for *anchors* or additional character escaping (as would be required with a regex).

Requests for this image (this exact URL) are then allowed through unencumbered.

The complete code would then look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mywebsite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?bing.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yahoo.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/wp-content/uploads/old_signature.gif
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|webp)$ https://www.dropbox.com/s/XXXXXXXXX/stop-hotlinking.png?raw=1 [NC,R,L]
```

---

#### Alternative - separate rule (exception)

Alternatively, if you don't have any other mod_rewrite rules in your `.htaccess` file that should apply to this request (unlikely) then you could instead add an additional rule (an exception) *before* the existing hotlink-protection script, at the very top of the `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
# Prevent further processing if this file is requested
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/old_signature\.gif$ - [L]

# Existing hotlink-protection script follows...
:
```

Note that this "alternative" solution assumes the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root, not a subdirectory.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work, unfortunately. I added

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/wp-content/uploads/old_signature.gif

at the right place in the code. But it does not work. Then I tried to change the URL to the https://www.exampledomain.com/wp-content/uploads/old_signature.gif

So I tried both versions:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/wp-content/uploads/old_signature.gif

AND

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=https://www.exampledomain.com/wp-content/uploads/old_signature.gif

but that does not work as well. PS: I don't know why paragraphs don't work in my comment.

Comment: @dajana.s Where is this `.htaccess` file? What other directives do you have in this file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories along the filesystem path? By "does not work" you presumably mean that you are redirected and the requested image is not displayed? That should not happen, even with your original script, when you make a direct request as you suggest (ie. by typing the URL into the browser's address bar, which I assume is what you mean by "change the URL to"?) since the `Referer` header will be empty and your first _condition_ excludes this.

Comment: @dajana.s "So I tried both versions" - where did you get the second version from? Your second version is certainly "wrong" as it will _always_ be successful. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path only.

Comment: @dajana.s Did you try the "alternative" (second) solution in my answer?

Comment: The Htaccess file is in the same folder where the "wp-content" folder is located. The Htaccess works fine, I use for many years in this location. Hotlinking prevention works fine too, only the exception described here for a specific file does not work. "Does not work" means that instead of the file to be excluded, the hotlinking image is displayed anyway (a stop sign). My 2nd version was just an attempt by me. I didn't try your alternative, because the Htaccess contains of course other mod_rewrite rules (it is the typical wordpress htaccess file).

Comment: @dajana.s "The Htaccess file is in the same folder where the "wp-content" folder is" - To clarify, the `.htaccess` file is in the document root, it's not _inside_ the `/wp-content` subdirectory? And there are no other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path? "I didn't try your alternative" - You should definitely try my "alternative" solution. The other mod_rewrite rules should not apply to this request anyway. Also make sure the browser cache is cleared (redirects can be cached). Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file, with these hotlinking directives in place.